# (High School Vectors) Distance between Parallel Lines

Tags: vectors

Given $2$ lines
$$L_1 : r = (1, 2, 3) + \lambda (1, 2, 1.5)\\
L_2 : r = (4, 0, -1) + \mu (2, 4, 3)$$

Are parallel to each other with points $A(1, 2, 3)$ and $B(4, 0, -1)$.
Determine the distance between the two lines.

---

Method 1: distance from a point B to line L1

$AB(\to) = OB(\to) - OA(\to) = (3, -2, -4)$

the distance is
$$\frac{|(3, -2, -4) \times (1, 2, 1.5) |}{\sqrt{1 + 4 + 2.25}}= 4.716$$

---

Method 2: foot of perpendicular

Let foot of perpendicular of $A$ on $L2$ be $F$

$$OF(→) = (4+2\mu, 4\mu, -1+3\mu) \text{ for some }\mu\in\mathbb R\\
AF(→) = (3+2\mu, 4\mu-2, -4+3\mu) $$
Since $AF$ perpendicular to $L2$ :
$$(3+2\mu, 4\mu-2, -4+3\mu) \cdot (2, 4, 3) = 0\\
μ = \frac{14}{29}\\
AF(\to) = \left(\frac{115}{29}, \frac{56}{29}, -\frac{74}{29}\right)\\
|AF(\to)| = 5.095$$

Method 3: Length of projection and Pythagoras Theorem

Length of projection of vector $\vec{AB}$ onto $L_1$:

$$\frac{|(3, -2, -4)\cdot (1, 2, 1.5)|}{\sqrt{1 + 4 + 2.25}} = 2.90065391$$

Length of $\vec{AB} = | (3, -2, -4) |$.

Distance between two lines by Pythagoras theorem:

$$\sqrt{| (3, -2, -4) |^2 - 2.90065391^2 } = 4.537237 . $$

Why do I get different answers for methods? I believe the three methods are correct.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question and want to close it? It's a perfectly legitimate question, OP is confused about a mathematical topic and wants help. It **could** use some latex, but that's hardly a reason to close it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector $AF$ should be $$\left(\frac{115}{29}, -\frac{2}{29}, -\frac{74}{29}\right)$$

This vector has a norm of approximately $4.716$ which is what you hot with method 1.

Your steps were correct up to the point where you inserted $\mu$ into the formula

$$AF = (3+2\mu, 4\mu - 2, -4+3\mu)$$

since

$$3+2\cdot \frac{14}{29} = \frac{87 + 28}{29} = \frac{115}{29}\\
4\cdot \frac{14}{29} - 2 = \frac{56 - 58}{29} = -\frac{2}{29}\\
-4+3\cdot\frac{14}{29} = \frac{-116 + 42}{29} = -\frac{74}{29}$$

Comment: @GuoJinLong Please format it correctly, like the rest of your question. Also, do this in future questions.

Comment: @GuoJinLong You made a mistake in calculating the length of projection. Redo the calculation to get the right result.